# I have an error generating my model from QuickType in xcode with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, quicktype

I am working with alamofire 4.0, I generate my models from QuickType a very useful tool, but I am getting this error. In the extension of Alamofire, I do not understand what can happen since all this class returns the QuickType console.

This is the model I got from quicktype with Alamofire extension

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class LoginResponse: Codable {
    let user: JSONNull?
    let status: Int
    let success: Bool
    let message: String

    init(user: JSONNull?, status: Int, success: Bool, message: String) {
        self.user = user
        self.status = status
        self.success = success
        self.message = message
    }
}

// MARK: Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}

fileprivate func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}

fileprivate func newJSONEncoder() -> JSONEncoder {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return encoder
}

// MARK: - Alamofire response handlers

extension DataRequest {
    fileprivate func decodableResponseSerializer<T: Decodable>() -> DataResponseSerializer<T> {
        return DataResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

            guard let data = data else {
                return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputDataNil))
            }

            return Result { try newJSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) }
        }
    }

    @discardableResult
    fileprivate func responseDecodable<T: Decodable>(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: decodableResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func responseLoginResponse(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<LoginResponse>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return responseDecodable(queue: queue, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

the error is in this line of code `fileprivate func decodableResponseSerializer<T: Decodable>() -> DataResponseSerializer<T>`:

```
fileprivate func decodableResponseSerializer<T: Decodable>() -> DataResponseSerializer<T> {
    return DataResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

        guard let data = data else {
            return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputDataNil))
        }

        return Result { try newJSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) }
    }
}
```

and this says

> Cannot specialize non-generic type 'DataResponseSerializer'

Comment: Are you using Swift 5?

Comment: I use xcode 10.1 and swift 4.2 @DávidPásztor

Comment: The issue is that QuickType generates code that uses Swift 5's `Result` type. Why are you using such an old version of Alamofire anyways, 4.0 has been released 3 years ago?

Comment: I already have the latest version of xcode 10.2 and swift 5, but now I get an error in another part of the code of the same method. @DávidPásztor, in the DataResponseSerializaer, I just updated my question.

Comment: did you ever figure out this issue?